# Can you simplify this?

Tags: calculus, statistics

From there :

$$\Large{
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi} \sigma_x } e^{ -\frac{(x-\mu_x)^2}{2\sigma^2_x}} 
                         \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi} \sigma_y } e^{ -\frac{(z-x-\mu_y)^2}{2\sigma^2_y}}}
 dx
$$

I should get there :

$$\Large{
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi ({\sigma_x^2 + \sigma_y^2)} }} e^{ -\frac{(z-\mu_x-\mu_y)^2}{2(\sigma^2_x + \sigma^2_y)}} 
}$$

And I get puzzled xD

Any hint is welcomeed :)

Comment: You'll have to be more specific, you haven't actually asked a question.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Your complete exponent is $-\frac{(x-\mu_x)^2}{2\sigma_x^2} - \frac{(z-x-\mu_y)^2}{2\sigma_y^2}$.
Try to bring that into the form $-A(x-B)^2 + C$ and use
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-A(x-B)^2 + C} dx = \sqrt{\frac \pi A} e^C$$